# How to make something run on batch close

Tags: batch-file

Essentially what I am trying to make is a batch file that starts another batch file checking wether the first batch file (original) is closed, and if so, echo something and then closes itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `wmic process list`, once the batchfile disappears you start your action.

Comment: How to detect when it closes then?

Comment: Using a while on the process list, combined with a `findstr`: once the batchfile gets removed from the process list (with `findstr`), you'll see one process less than before.

Comment: Could you make an example, I really am not getting it. Sorry.

Comment: This isn't a code request site, please attempt the task yourself. It should be simple enough to create the first script which runs the other and performs a timeout before closing itself. You can then practice and test the content of the second script with little chance of anything going wrong.